# last cell must take all remaining space left in the tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I want my last cell to take all the remaining space left in the tableview. So I wrote this piece of code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) - 1 {
        let sectionheight: CGRect = tableView.rect(forSection: 0)
        let tableViewFrame: CGRect = tableView.frame
        let height: CGFloat = tableViewFrame.size.height - (sectionheight.size.height - 100)


        cell.frame.size.height = height
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

and in the heightForRow for that cell I return just a value of like 100.

The problem is that the height calculated is correct but the cell doesn't change.

How can I make sure the cells height is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do height calculation in `heightForRow`, not in `willDisplayCell`, you can also save some property first in `willDisplayCell` then call `tableView.beginUpdate` and `endUpdate` to force recalculation cell height

The cell doesnt change because the tableview handle cell height, not the cell, the cell only control it's content height